# What is a word similar to FYI but not objective/neutral?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, formality, abbreviations, register

FYI can be used in an email to inform the person reading the email about some information. It is comfortable using this between peers. But what if the mail is intended to inform someone higher in the hierarchy(manager or director of a group) about something. Is there a short phrase instead of writing "Just want to inform you, ...", etc.

FYI, sounds a bit bland and too neutral. I want the word to convey some respect too.

Comment: If your email is mail is "intended to inform someone higher in the hierarchy", they'd probably rather you just told them whatever it is you need to tell them, and not waste their time (which they would consider more valuable than *yours*) reading pointless extra verbiage.

Comment: We all use pointless extra verbiage, sometimes for good reason.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Welcome to the site!

I can see your dilemma, and in the future I would tag this type of question with "register" and "formality," just to be clear.

It is true that sometimes we couch statements or questions in more formal or polite language in certain circumstances, and yours sounds like one of those situations. I would certainly not use FYI in certain formal writing situations. Perhaps one of these might work:

**I'd just like to bring to your attention...** + an issue / a recent discovery / an interesting fact

**I would just like to update you on...**

**I'd like to notify you that...**

ADDED (based on poster's request for shorter expressions):

Two strong candidates for shorter expressions that are highly synonymous with FYI:

**Just so you know**...

**Just so you're aware**...

My only hesitation is that you indicated that you want to convey some respect, and politeness in English (and many other languages) is conveyed - in part - by lengthening and indirection (with modals, past tense, hedges, and hypotheticals). For example, if I want to know what time it is, I could just ask "What time is it?" However, that might sound too abrupt if I'm speaking to someone I don't know or to someone to whom I should show respect. But I could say:

*Do you know what time it is?*

*I was wondering if you have the time...*

*Would you happen to have the time?*

Or, if you want to get almost sickeningly polite, you could try:

*I'm terribly sorry to bother you, but I was wondering if you happened to know the time.*

The excessive verbiage serves an important sociolinguistic function.

Comment: Wondering if there are any shorter versions that have a similar meaning as the phrases you suggested.

Comment: You could also suggest, "I thought I'd keep you in the loop on this."

Answer (score 2):

Instead of ***FYI***, you can write ***For your information***.

In my opinion and experience, "for your information" is acceptable to inform someone higher in the hierarchy about something (for example, about an e-mail thread) and it is obviously more formal than its abbreviation FYI.

It is better to be precise (without being impolite) than including stuffy formalities that makes sentences intolerably long and that can obscure the message.

You can also consider:

- **Please be informed** that...
- **Kindly be informed** that...